# GUI based svn+diff tool in LINUX for directories comparison

Tags: linux, svn, user-interface, diff

I'm trying to find a good combination of svn and diff tools in LINUX, hope someone can give me some suggestions.

I'm currently using rapidsvn+meld. This combination works fine for me most of time, but I don't like it when it comes to directory comparison.

Does anyone know a good combination of GUI based svn+diff which can ease directory comparison tasks?

Thanks,
Yang

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to use GUI :P but personally from what all I have used, I feel Gnome Commander is one of the best tools available for the diff thingy you want. Its very very powerful in terms of utility.

Other options  you would like to explore are Beyond Compare (also good one) and Guiffy.

For SVN, I would say to stick with rapidSVN only.

Answer (score 0):

Look at tools by Syntevo. For SVN you may use [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) or [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) (I prefer SmartGit).
For directories comparison --- [SmartSynchronize](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsynchronize/index.html).